# Overload get_FIELD_display() function

Tags: django, django-models

Is there a way to overload Django's `get_FIELD_display()` function properly? When I call the function from inside itself, the result is a recursion. But I can't call it using `super()` either, as it's not a parent class' method but a method created by the metaclass...

The goal is to have a common interface for getting a displayable version of a `CHOICE` field  (which is given by `get_FIELD_display`), but with the possibility to customize it in some specific cases.

Example:

```
# This does not work because it results in recursion
def get_opposition_state_display(self):
    """Overloading of default function."""
    value = self.get_opposition_state_display()
    if self.opposition_state == 4: 
        return '%s %s' % (value, self.opposition_date.strftime('%d.%m.%Y'))
    return value
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**updated**

```
field = self._meta.get_field('opposition_state')
value = self._get_FIELD_display(field)
```

Comment: This seems like the Right Way to go about it, as `_get_FIELD_display()` is the function `Field.contribute_to_class()` curries and injects into the model class.

Comment: Edit: Sorry, I have to correct myself. It does not work, as the `_get_FIELD_display` method expects a field as an argument, not a string. And at the time of calling my own `get_opposition_state_display` method, that field has already been turned into a property of the class... https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/base.py#L581

Comment: i guess you could pull it out of self._meta, but at that point it may feel less hacky to just copy the code (all 2 lines of it) out of `get_FIELD_display`

Comment: Thanks, that helped. Resulting code: `field = self._meta.get_field('opposition_state'); value = self._get_FIELD_display(field)`. I think this is cleaner than copying the code, as in that case I'd have to supply the name of the CHOICES tuple, which contradicts DRY. Maybe you could put that solution into your answer?

Answer (score 2):

To override get_FOO_display you need something like this:

```
field_name = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField('Field', choices=some_choices)

def _get_FIELD_display(self, field):
    f_name = field.name
    if f_name == 'field_name':
        return 'what_you_need'
    return super(YourModelName, self)._get_FIELD_display(field=field)
```